# Css Table doesn't work

Tags: php, css-tables

I want to modify my table by CSS, but it doesn't work, the only CSS part that doesn't work is the table.
The rest of the CSS works correctly.

The PHP code:

```
   <table style="width:100%">
           <tr>
            <td>Nif</td>
            <td>Nom</td>        
            <td>Cognoms</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Provincia</td>
           </tr>

   <?php 
      while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado2)) {
        $Nif =$fila[0];
        $Nombre=$fila[1];
        $Cognoms=$fila[2];
        $Fecha=$fila[3];
        $Provincia=$fila[4];
       echo"<tr>";
       echo"<td>$Nif</td>";
       echo"<td>$Nombre</td>";      
       echo"<td> $Cognoms</td>";
       echo"<td> $Fecha</td>";
       echo"<td>$Provincia</td>";
       echo"</tr>";
     echo" </table>";
     }

     mysqli_close($con);

     ?>
```

Part of the CSS:

```
input#boton{
    color:white;
    font-size:2em;
    background-color:#00BFFF;
    height:0.8cm;
    border:2px;
    width:80%;
    margin-top:1%;
     margin-left:10%;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        -ms-border-radius:5px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
}

input#boton:hover{

    background-color:#2EFE2E;

}

table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: blue;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: What is the problem? Does the css affect "table", "th" and "td" at all?

Comment: what result are you expecting and what result are you getting?

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain clearly ! .the css for the table doesn't work at all,but the rest of the css works well.

Comment: Check the HTML sent to the browser

Comment: close your "table" tag after loop and not inside. in your example you have "<table>bla bla</table>bla bla</table>...." after the php script was done...

Answer (score 3):

For each row, you print `echo" </table>";` You should put it at the end of the while loop.

Comment: That's an error ! but the css for the table still does not work .i've got no border,no background colour, not a thing that i set on the css .

Comment: it works fine, try! if you close "table" tag inside of the loop, your css work's only for first loop run, but not for the rest. why? after first run is the rest html not more a part of table, because is outside of table tag!

Comment: Please check my answer as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your Php code. you must not print table in each row.

while(){

}